# Angular/UI Router-or-directive for toggling submenu content

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Examples of two menus with similar behaviours:[menu example 1](http://www.rga.com/about/locations/stockholm/)
and [menu example 2](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalSlideOutMenu/)
Both are implemented with jquery. I want an angular implementation if possible.
I would like to toggle my partials as you see there without the use of jquery at all.
I have tried with the following approach:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yttY9PrZBdgeUZfQXXMx?p=preview--a menu/submenu directive
(plunker found here at stackoverflow )

I both considered modifying the bootstrap 3 nav bar and hoped to use it with ui-router but I 
do not believe there is any easy way to use ui-router to achieve this toggling of states from the
same menu selection.

Here is the css for arrow down:

```
.arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #000;
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated. I just need a push.

Comment: Why don't you use the Plunker example ?

Comment: After a few weeks of trying, I just find it extremely challenging so if no one can help I will need to look for other avenues. I hope someone more skillful can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle to my question:
[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/CCe3x/)

```
<submenu  data-caption="Contact">
  <div class='arrow-down'></div>
  <pre><div ng-include src="'style.css'"></div></pre>
</submenu>
```

The partials are of course injected using ng-include and only if you remember those pesky ''.
The fiddle wont display the .css file which was added for proof of concept but this works in plunker.
Also this example uses a minimum of not-so-great-css. My next step will be to see if the many css selectors needed can be packed in without sacrificing too much on readability. If you jquery guys check out the amount of js code needed for this as opposed to the minimal amount of code written in the directive---it quite a "shocking" difference. Will post a better version if i get that far and i still think this toggle between clicks behaviour would be a good option to add in ui-router.